# Spring data Elasticsearch count in groups by date range

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I use spring data elastic search and have a this list in my elastic search.

```
{"appUserId": "id-test-app-user11",   "apkId": 1,   "event": "INSTALL",  "date": "2020-06-01"}
...
{"appUserId": "id-test-app-user168",   "apkId": 1,   "event": "INSTALL",  "date": "2020-12-06"}
```

I want to count by day the number of install of an apkId between a date range.

With this request, I can get all data bewteen my date range and an apkId provided in parameter

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();                  
LocalDate beginningDate = today.minusDays(intervalle);

BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
query.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date") 
        .gte(convertToDateViaInstant(beginningDate))  
        .lte(convertToDateViaInstant(today)));
query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("apkId", apkId));
query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("event", Event.INSTALL));


return apkHistoryRepo.search(query);
```

But I don't know how to aggregate by date in order to have something like

```
{"2020-06-01": "500"}
...
{"2020-12-06": "10"}
```

Please how could I achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution in Java

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();                  
        LocalDate beginningDate = today.minusDays(intervalle);

        BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        query.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date") 
                .gte(beginningDate)  
                .lte(today));
        query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("apkId", apkId));
        query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("event", Event.INSTALL));

        Iterable<ApkHistory> list = apkHistoryRepo.search(query);

        AggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
                .dateHistogram("nb_install_per_day")
                .field("date")
                .dateHistogramInterval(DateHistogramInterval.DAY);


        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("apkhistory"); 
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(query).aggregation(aggregation);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder); 

        try {
            SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

            ParsedDateHistogram dateGroupBy = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("nb_install_per_day");

        List<? extends Histogram.Bucket> bucketList = dateGroupBy.getBuckets();
        for(Bucket b : bucketList) {
            
            System.out.println(b.getKeyAsString() + " "+b.getDocCount());
            
        }
            System.out.println("test");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [date histogram](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation. Here is how you can use it in your query,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "apkId": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "event": "INSTALL"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": <start_date_here>,
              "lte": <end_date_here>
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "per_day_count": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "calendar_interval": "1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser. Do you know or have an example with QueryBuilders ?